# Looking for a substring in Velocity

Tags: string, apache, velocity

I am looking for a method in velocity where I can put a check on certain part of string and carry on with subsequent methods. I tried with the following:
But it throws an error that 'contains' function is unrecognized.

```
##Check whether a certain string is a sub part of other string
#set($Name="")
#set($SomeName="ABC DEF"
#set($Name=$SomeName)
#if($Name.contains("DE"))
Correct!
#end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance i found that there is a mistake bracket not close

```
#set($SomeName="ABC DEF"
```

should be changed to

```
#set($SomeName="ABC DEF")
```

Other than that i don't think there is a problem with contains function . i have tested it is working fine with me .